# Get the unevaluated expression from a numbered cell

Tags: evaluation, cells

If a cell exists as below:

```
In[1] := (xyPoints = {{1,2},{2,5},{3,10}}; ListLinePlot[xyPoints])
```

Is it possible to get at the expression rather than the plot shown in Out[1]. In other words, can I somehow get the held CompoundExpression in In[1] rather than the evaluated plot?

Comment: DownValues[In][[2]]

Comment: Awesome. Looks like I can use something like: DownValues[In][[1]] /. RuleDelayed[x_, y_] :> HoldComplete[y]

Comment: Interestingly, this does not work if there is a newline after the semicolon.

Comment: You could also use `Information[In]` or `ToExpression[InString[1], StandardForm, Hold]`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111963/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-a-previous-un-evaluated-un-normalized-input/164312#164312

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `InString` for that:

```
ToExpression[InString[1], StandardForm, Hold]
```

> Hold[xyPoints = {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 10}}; ListLinePlot[xyPoints]]

Comment: Great. Do you know if there a way to get all the lines in a cell? If a compound expression is spread over multiple lines, each line seems to correspond to a different In[x] number.

Comment: @teedr You could try to experiment with `DownValues[InString]` for that.

Comment: In addition to the problem with multiple lines, this answer will not retain all the [2D input formatting](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput.html) that your original cell might have had.  That means you cannot use this answer to recover exactly what you had in an input cell that you, say, accidentally deleted.  To recover everything, use [Carl Woll's answer to a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164312/1806).

Answer (score 3):

```
Cells[CellLabel -> "In[1]:="] // First // NotebookRead // 
  First // MakeExpression
```

gives

```
HoldComplete[xyPoints = {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 10}}; 
 ListLinePlot[xyPoints]]
```