# Is it possible to retrieve a previous un-evaluated, un-normalized input?

Tags: notebooks, printing, input-forms

For example, if I do this:

```
In[42]:= {{2}, {3}} // MatrixForm
```

where `In[42]:=` is the notebook prompt, I am looking for some way to get back `{{2}, {3}} // MatrixForm`.  (Which I guess would be a string?  Or some kind of unevaluated expression?)

The closest I can find is `In[42] // InputForm`, which in this case gives me `MatrixForm[{{2}, {3}}]`.

Is this possible, or is the actual tree structure of an entered input not recoverable?

Comment: closely related: [How do I extract the contents of a selected cell as plain text?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1319/5478)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164312/9490) for a better answer.

Just a slight modification of Mechanical snail's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15514/9490), (I need a more creative username...) to make the output match the input exactly.

```
In[1]:= {{2}, {3}} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
In[2]:= ToExpression[InString[1], StandardForm, Defer] // DisplayForm
```

[image]

Which you can copy/paste, or just append `//CopyToClipboard` to the command above and you can just paste it and use it.  This will work with other automatically parsed expressions like `2+3` as well.

Comment: thanks JasonB!  exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note that this answer will not retain all the [2D input formatting](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput.html) that your original cell might have had.  That means you cannot use this answer to recover exactly what you had in an input cell that you, say, accidentally deleted.  To recover everything, use Carl Woll's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea is to [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) the [`InString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InString) output:

```
reprintInput[n_] := CellPrint @ Cell[
    BoxData[ToExpression@InString[n]],
    "Input"
]
```

For your example:

```
$Line=41;
{{2}, {3}} //MatrixForm
```

[image]

Then, `reprintInput` produces an exact copy of the original input cell:

```
reprintInput[42]
```

> {{2}, {3}} // MatrixForm

If you just want to store an unevaluated version of the input somewhere, you could use something like:

```
input = ToExpression[ToExpression@InString[42], StandardForm, Hold];
input //InputForm
```

> Hold[MatrixForm[{{2}, {3}}]]

This is similar to @JasonB.'s answer, but there is no need to use copy/paste.

Comment: Thank you!  This actually recovered my complete input cell (which I had accidentally deleted, and mysteriously was undo-able).  This saved me tremendous time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible by reading the `In`, since the information is stored in a list of `HoldPattern` expression, and your input is not preserved. But if you did not delete the input cell, it is possible to obtain your input by doing this:

```
CellPrint@
Cell[Cases[NotebookRead@Cells[], 
Cell[x_, _, _, CellLabel -> "In[42]:="] -> x][[1]], "Input"]
```

You can get exactly your input in a new cell.

Comment: thanks happy fish.  filing away for future use.