# How to see the definition of `In[n_]` for some `n`?

Tags: input, hold

After running the code

```
In[1]:= a = 2;
In[2]:= ++a

Out[2]= 3
```

if `In[2]` is evaluated repeatedly, `a` keeps increasing, so the unevaluated form is stored.
If, however, the cell is deleted from the notebook and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> doesn't reach sufficiently far, how to restore the unevaluated form?

Comment: you can see it in `DownValues[In]`

Comment: see this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111969/9490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that `In` is just a symbol, with `DownValues` you can inspect. For instance, with your inputs,

```
FirstCase[DownValues[In],
  HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern[In[2]]] :> _]]
(* HoldPattern[In[2]] :> ++a *)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to looking at the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) of [`In`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/In), you could also make use of [`InString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InString):

```
$Line = 0;
a = 2;
++a;

ToExpression[
    ToExpression[InString[1]],
    StandardForm,
    Defer
]
```

> a = 2;

*(I see that this answer is close to a duplicate of @JasonB's link in the comments. I will leave it, though, as I don't like using [`DisplayForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayForm))*

Comment: Your comment made me wonder why I used `DisplayForm` there (I don't really know what it does).  I didn't notice your double use of `ToExpression`, which seems to have some evaluation if the original input is `{{2}, {3}} // MatrixForm`

Comment: @JasonB. `DisplayForm` basically converts the parts of the input that are expressions into boxes, and then renders those boxes. I don't like `DisplayForm` because something like `"1"` could be either a string expression, or the box form of `1`, so `DisplayForm` has to use heuristics to decide what to do. As for your example, what kind of evaluation are you talking of? When I use my code on that example, I get the expected `Defer[MatrixForm[{{2}, {3}}]]`.

Comment: When I run it, it still displays in `MatrixForm` - https://i.imgur.com/I7tNH8e.png.  I don't know why my results are different from yours.  I appreciate that the front end uses boxes for everything, but if it does it well then I don't ever have to think about them :-)  I just prefer for everything box-related to be abstracted away.

Comment: Isn't `MatrixForm` part of the input? Why would it go away? I see the same thing you do.

Comment: this may be off topic since it doesn't so much relate to this question.  But take the `XXXForm` out of it.  I took the other question to mean that if the input string was `1 // f // g` then it would be wrong for the return to be `g[ f[ 1] ]`.  Is your point that it isn't the evaluator that turns the former into the latter, and therefore no evaluation occurred?

Comment: @JasonB. Yes, look at `HoldComplete[1 // f // g] //FullForm`.